# MySQL - How to maintain acceptable response time while querying with many filters (Should I use Redis?)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, redis

I have a table called `users` with a couple dozen columns such as `height`, `weight`, `city`, `state`, `country`, `age`, `gender` etc...

The only keys/indices on the table are for the columns `id` and `email`.

I have a search feature on my website that filters users based on these various columns. The query could contain anywhere from zero to a few dozen different where clauses (such as `` where `age` > 40 ``).

The search is set to `LIMIT 50` and `` ORDER BY `id` ``.

There are about 100k rows in the database right now.

If I perform a search with zero filters or loose filters, mysql basically just returns the first 50 rows and doesn't have to read very many more rows than that. It usually takes less than 1 second to complete this type of query.

If I create a search with a lot of complex filters (for instance, 5+ where clauses), MySQL ends up reading through the entire database of 100k rows, trying to accumulate 50 valid rows, and the resulting query takes about 30 seconds.

How can I more efficiently query to improve the response time?

I am open to using caching (I already use Redis for other caching purposes, but I don't know where to start with properly caching a MySQL table).

I am open to adding indices, although there are a lot of different combinations of where clauses that can be built. Also, several of the columns are JSON where I am searching for rows that contain certain elements. To my knowledge I don't think an index is a viable solution for that type of query.

I am using MySQL version 8.0.15.

Comment: It should not take 30s to search through just 100k rows, unless your server is pretty wimpy

Comment: I would also expect a full table scan on a 100K rows table being performed somwhere around 100ms (on a medium consumer PC). What is the table size in MB?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The db server is an AWS db.t2.micro (1 vCPU, 1 GB memory, low-to-moderate network performance).

What is recommended spec for a production system? @ysth

Comment: @PaulSpiegel The table is 869 MB, although only a handful of columns are returned / read.

Comment: Ideally the entire DB fits into RAM and innodb buffer.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Can you elaborate on what you mean by it fitting into RAM and innodb buffer? Does that just mean if the DB is 1GB, then you should have at least 1GB RAM and 1GB innodb buffer? And the mysql server handles caching the DB into ram on its own?

Comment: The [innodb buffer pool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html) is kind of cache, holding frequently used data in memmory. If it's big enough, it can hold the entire database, and read (select) operations don't need to access the disc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the responses in the comments from ysth and Paul, the problem was just the server capacity. After upgrading the an 8GB RAM server, to query times dropped to under 1s.

Answer (score 1):

In general you need to create indexes for the columns which are mentioned in the criteria of the WHERE clauses. And you can also create indexes for JSON columns, use generated column index: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html.